# Base16 & neovim. How to use consistent colors in both linux VT and X terminal?

Tags: shell, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

Recently, I've configured my shell using base16 color scheme using this script: https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell/blob/master/scripts/base16-default-dark.sh. And Neovim's color scheme using: https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim.

Then I've set the following in ".vimrc" or more precisely `.config/init/init.vim`:

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'chriskempson/base16-vim'
...
set background=dark
let base16colorspace=256
colorscheme base16-default-dark
```

Everything works quite ok excerpt I can't change LineNumber column color but this is another story:

[image]

What I've realized is that when I switch to VT (tty) my colors are really messed up within Neovim. I see that VT or ($TERM=linux) supports only 8/16 colors which isn't the case when I under $TERM=screen/tmux/st(-256color). So the `base16-shell` schemes apply colors differently in accordance with $TERM. So the question is how to force Neovim (or the color scheme itself) be conscious of how applying the colors being under VT and X terminal?

Answer (score 10):

I've had the exact same problem. iTerm2 + fish + nvim + tmux + fzf. Everything worked great with base16-shell and base16-vim but the colors were messed up in nvim under tmux. Took me two days to figure it out. The following two tmux settings fixed it for me.

```
set -g  default-terminal "screen-256color"
# needed for proper nvim/tmux/base16 colors
set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
```

Comment: Thanks! Data point: Arch Linux, Alacritty, tmux, nvim. Works like a charm.

Comment: chriskempson/base16-vim and your dotfiles repos are both deleted as of now